# how to install AWSCLI on a Anaconda python distribution

Tags: python, anaconda, aws-cli

I followed instructions as per:

```
https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/awscli/README.html#installation
```

executed: `conda install awscli`

Result:

```
Fetching package metadata: ....

Solving package specifications: .

Error:  Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 

  - awscli

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda awscli

You may need to install the anaconda-client command line client with

    conda install anaconda-client
```

Comment: Please see the setup aswell: https://bioconda.github.io/index.html#setup

Answer (score 43):

Now you can get it from conda-forge, a set of community maintained conda recipes.

```
conda install -c conda-forge awscli
```

source: [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/awscli)

Comment: Thanks! This is the only way I was able to get aws to run on the command line. Doing a pip install allowed my access it from within python, but not as a standalone executable.

Answer (score 4):

After you have installed Anaconda, ensure that your default Python is the Anaconda installation by running your profile file, for example, in bash:

```
$source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, install Aws CLI with pip (sudo not required):

```
$pip install awscli
```

You can then verify that the installation was successful. For example, I had the same issue. I verified it thus:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import s3transfer
>>> quit()
```

Comment: sir, i did it successfully. But I want to make aws as cli command. I cant find awscli location. How to find it ?